# Php Import large csv breaking when it is 64 mb

Tags: php, jquery, import

I have 64 mb data in csv , when ever am trying to get data in the csv, its breaking, i want to get all data in one short,Here is my code.

```
$filename = $_FILES['inputfile']['tmp_name'];
$inputfilename = $_FILES['inputfile']['name'];
if (($handle = fopen($filename, "r")) !== FALSE) {
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 5000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
$strContent[] = $data;
}
fclose($handle);
}
$_arrData = $strContent;
```

how can i get that.

Answer (score 0):

maybe because your php.ini limits file upload to 64mb. try to add:

```
upload_max_filesize = 128M
post_max_size = 128M
```

to your php.ini.

or use .htaccess instead(only if your webhosting/webserver allows it):

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 128M
php_value post_max_size 128M
```

because you may need to restart webserver after modifying php.ini.

P.S: Don't use ini_set() function, use php.ini file instead. Because those upload_max_filesize and post_max_size cannot be altered on run-time. uploads of file larger than the value specified in php.ini will result in fail before the parser execute your ini_set() function.

Comment: which method did you just used?

Comment: or maybe it's because your php memory limit. also try to increase your memory limit by  `memory_limit = 128M` in your php.ini.

Comment: ini_set('memory_limit','500M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '600');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '128M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '128M');

Comment: well. You cannot change these values at run-time; uploads of file larger than the value specified in php.ini will have failed by the time execution reaches your call to ini_set.